# How to move coins without blockchain?

Tags: wallets, nodes

Is there a way to move coins from one account to another (both in the same Ethereum node) without publishing it on blockchain? 
On a Bitcoin Node I can do it with "move" command. Is there an equivalent for Ethereum?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible. Accounts do not belong to any node. They belong to the blockchain, and each node keeps a copy of the blockchain. A transfer between 2 accounts is a transaction. And transaction need to be published to the network and mined into a block in order to be completed.

Comment: So it's a different structure then Bitcoin. Because on bitcoin, when you create addresses(accounts), it creates them in the same wallet and you can move coins between them without any mining. This is very useful for exchange platforms.

Comment: You are probably talking of a mechanism specific to some bitcoin wallets. Any modification of the data of the blockchain needs to be done in transactions which are mined. Thats the very basis of the blockchain security. If you think my answer is correct please mark this answer as accepted, thank you :)

Comment: You can check the answer on this link to understand me better: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/how-does-the-move-command-work
I'm still hopeful that Ethereum has such a feature (I really need it :) ). Let's wait a little bit more.